# Generate square wave for analog input/output on software

Tags: c, driver, analog-digital-converter, digital-analog-converter

I have a device, and it has digital i/o, analog i/o. I send to device below commands for communication.The device has gpio module. My device documantation is [here](http://www.numato.com/productdoc/usbgpio16/16ChannelUSBGPIOModuleV7.pdf)

Write to digital input : `gpio set/clear x`
Read from digital output : `gpio read x`
Read from digital output : `adc read x`
(x : pin number)

How can I create sine/square wave and calculate amplitude? To create square wave :

- open device
- sleep
- write to device low mode(t0)
- sleep
- write to device high mode
- sleep
- write to device low mode(t1)

period = (t1 - t0)

Is this a square wave?

Comment: hmm it seems that you are writing SW for USB to GPIO reduction so this is not a code directly for MCU but for PC? instead sending data via some driver into that USB board. You should add some info about it and even a retag would be a good idea (add the device name into tags if possible). so now I am not sure if mine answer is Good for this (there can be timing issues) is you device synchronous IO port or asynchronous (are you setting the times when the IO should toggle or read or when you send the command then it is executed + some delay of coarse?)

Answer (score 2):

it seems your example is indeed square wave

if `write to device low mode(t0)` sets the output pin to low and `write to device low mode(t1)` to high or reverse then period is the sum of the sleeps + some time for setting up **GPIO** state. Don't know why you have times inside the **GPIO** set lines and not in sleeps ... (may be something platform dependent?)

To go to sin wave

use **DAC** or **PWM + RC filter** with some precomputed amplitude table in which the index is increasing periodically.

```
BYTE sintab[32]={ 128,...,255,...,128,...,0,....,127  };
```

encoded: `128` is zero, `255` is `+1` and `0` is `-1`; now just add some index:

```
int ix=0'
```

and once in a while (on some timer perhaps) increment it and set the output to new value:

```
ix=(ix+1)&31;
```

that and `31` just cause tho cycle the index from start again if end reached (sintab must be of size power of 2). The period is timer frequency/sintab size

**[notes]**

You can modify this to your purpose for example make `sintab[][]` a 2D array where first index means amplitude and second is the `ix` as now. On older platforms (MCU's) you can encode the **PWM** sequence directly to `sintab` end so on ...

You can pre-compute the `sintab` values like this:

```
sintab[ix]=128.0+127.0*sin(float(2.0*M_PI*ix)/32.0);
```

or if your platform supports fast enough `sin` you can use above line directly without the actual array ...

**[edit1]**

for `sinwave` you can use just `0/1` states. If you need analog output and:

1. **You have DAC (digital to analog converter)**

   then send the actual amplitude to it like `dac write sintab[ix];` that will create the analog voltage on the output pin for you.
2. **You do not have any spare DAC's use PWM Pulse Width Modulation instead**

   it is an old school trick to avoid the need of **DAC** and still have analog output from digital pin. It works like this:

   The output value is the cumulative energy/voltage per time chunk so you generate square-wave signal

   - ratio 1:1 means that half the period is H and the rest L
   - ratio 2:1 means that 2/3 of the period is H and the rest L

   The more time the output is H the bigger output value. This is still digital output but if you connect on it any nonlinear device like capacitor or coil then the `energy inertia` will cause to drop the H voltage to some level dependent on the square-wave ratio. Most common is the **RC** filter (**R** is serial and **C** is parallel to ground). If you want to drive some coil (motor) then you do not need the filter. This kind of use usually generate high pitch sound (the PWM frequency) often heard near machinery ...

   [image: img]

   The **PWM** frequency has to be high enough (many times higher then the sinwave frequency)

Some code for **PWM** with amplitude and frequency setting:

```cpp
const int timer_T=1;        // used timer interval [ms]
const int PWM_max=10;       // PWM max amplitude+1 
int PWM_s=0;                 // PWM actual step
int PWM_t=0;                 // PWM actual time

int PWM_a=3;                 // PWM amplitude <0,PWM_ratio_max)
int PWM_T=200;               // PWM period [ms]

void OnTimer()
 {
 int PWM_T0=PWM_T/PWM_max; // PWM step period must be >=1 !!!
 PWM_t+=timer_T;
 if (PWM_t>=PWM_T0)
  {
  if (PWM_s<=pwm_a) gpio set x; else gpio clear x;
  PWM_s++; if (PWM_s>=PWM_max) PWM_s=0;
  PWM_t-=PWM_T0;
  }
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand that how I use sin table. I can set the output only 0 or 1. But the numbers in the table are different. For example, the number is 128, should I set "0"?

Comment: @sdn the device does not have DAC only ADC so you have to go for PWM. first create functional square-wave (check by osciloscope or LED) with variable ratio and fixed frequency (sleep(t0),sleep(t1) t0+t1=constant, t0/t1 is the ratio). if done then implement sintab ... if you do not have osciloscope then you still can use LED's if PWM f is high > 1KHz and sinwave freq is low 0.1Hz then you should see the brightness change ...

Comment: @Sdn added some code for PWM in C++ (wrote directly inside Opera so there can be typos) the more faster timer the more amplitude steps or higher PWM frequency you can obtain